# Pasar varios String a Int

Tags: java

Espero que se encuentren bien.

Tengo el siguiente código...

```
int x = 1 
int y = 2

String xx= String.valueOf(x); 
String yy= String.valueOf(y); 
String xy= "("+xx+","+yy+")" ; 
return xx;
```

Quisiera saber si existe una forma de convertir esos dos INT  sin tener que usar dos veces `String.valueOf`.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Java cuando "sumas" un `String` y un `int` da como resultado un `String`, o sea, no necesitas hacer la conversión.

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;

String str = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
return str;
// str = "(1,2)"
```

Pero si aún así lo necesitas, no, hasta donde sé no hay forma de hacer un typecast por lotes. Aunque para "ahorrar" en código puedes sumarle un `String` vacío `""` al `int` y listo, queda más simple la conversión.

Fuente: [How to convert an integer to a string in Java](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-string-in-java)